# Can I bypass a sites login page with a form POST?

Tags: asp.net, forms, post, single-sign-on

I am trying to integrate a product offered by a 3rd party into my web site. This 3rd party does not have the resources to make code changes for a single sign-on type of setup so I am looking for a way to provide a similar user experience through some possible shortcuts. One that I am considering is to use an HTML POST to post the login credentials directly to the form on the login page which would hopefully bypass the page all together and direct the user directly to the home page fully authenticated. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's possible. i believe that most well made authentication will have some sort of nonce in its form, which is essentially to ensure that unless you use their form to submit, the submission will be rejected.

and even if currently they don't have nonce, in the future they might have